# symfony twig dynamic from action path

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.6

I have a form, I want to change its path of action using js variable.

This is current working code:

```
if ($('#totalRecordsOfQuery').val() < 100) {
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path('_getAllRecordsStudentsProgress') }}");
    $('#postbackform').submit();
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path('xyz) }}");
}
```

I want something like:

```
var allRecordsActions = "_getAllRecordsStudentsProgress";
if ($('#totalRecordsOfQuery').val() < 100) {
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path(allRecordsActions) }}");
    $('#postbackform').submit();
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path('xyz') }}");
}
```

With this code, I'm getting an error:

> Variable "allRecordsActions" does not exist.

Comment: the code is inside a twig file (or something processed by the TWIG rendering engine)?

Comment: it is in twig file

Answer (score 0):

```
var allRecordsActions = "_getAllRecordsStudentsProgress";
var concatenation= '{{ path("'+ allRecordsActions +'") }}';
        if($('#totalRecordsOfQuery').val()<100){
            $('#postbackform').attr('action', concatenation);
            $('#postbackform').submit();
            $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path('xyz') }}");
        }
```

or

```
var allRecordsActions = "_getAllRecordsStudentsProgress";
if($('#totalRecordsOfQuery').val()<100){
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', '{{ path("'+ allRecordsActions +'") }}');
    $('#postbackform').submit();
    $('#postbackform').attr('action', "{{ path('xyz') }}");
}
```

Comment: Both not working, have tried many combination like this, nothing working out

Comment: you can instal js route bundle https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html its the best way to manipulate with routes in javascript Symfony